# Replacing text recursively in many .txt using different dictionaries (UNIX)

Tags: unix, replace

I need to modify some characters in a large number of .txt files using custom made dictionaries. Every .txt file starts with the same kind of header, following this model:

# title: That Old Black Magic

# artist: Louis Prima & Keely Smith

# metre: 4/4

# tonic: C

I want to use the "tonic: " information above to indicate which dictionary to use. So far I can modify each file manually following this command line:

```
awk -f script.sh dict0.txt "input.txt" >> "output.txt"
```

where script.sh is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh


NR == FNR {
  rep[$1] = $2
  next
}

{
    for (key in rep) {
      gsub(key, rep[key])
    }
print
}
```

and where the dict0.txt is the dictionary associated with "tonic: C"

This procedure allows me to modify a single file correctly, but forces me to manually choose which dictionary to use, and to specify every input file. I'd like to be able to modify many (700+) files without specifying which dictionary to use. I've created a file that's called index.txt that indicates which dictionary should be used for each specific tonic. The content of the index is the following:

```
tonic: B#   dict0
tonic: C    dict0
tonic: C#   dict1
tonic: Db   dict1
tonic: D    dict2
tonic: D#   dict3
tonic: Eb   dict3
tonic: E    dict4
tonic: Fb   dict4
tonic: E#   dict5
tonic: F    dict5
tonic: F#   dict6
tonic: Gb   dict6
tonic: G    dict7
tonic: G#   dict8
tonic: Ab   dict8
tonic: A    dict9
tonic: A#   dict10
tonic: Bb   dict10
tonic: B    dict11
tonic: Cb   dict11
```

I should also mention that all the files are located in different sub-folders of a main folder.

Am I dreaming in technicolor? Is this possible to do in a not too complicated way?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could proceed. Given what you already have and the number of files you mention (unless each dictionary or file is very large), the simplest is wrap your `awk` above in a shell script. You can find all the files of one dictionary type per pass:

```
for dt in "B# C C# Db ..."; do
    find inputs -type f -print | egrep -l 'tonic: $dt" | while read filename; do
        outname=`echo $filename | sed 's#inputs/#outs/#'`
        awk -f script.sh "dicts/%dt" $filename > "$outname"
    done
done
```

Alternatively, figure out which dictionary to use for each file:

```
find inputs -type f -print | while read filename; do
    td =`sed -q -e '4s/tonic: *//p' $filename`
    outname=`echo $filename | sed 's#inputs/#outs/#'`
    awk -f script.sh "dicts/$td" "$outname"
done
```

(Note: I haven't tested these; obviously, I don't have your input files)

Another way would be to extend the misleadingly named `script.sh` (should be `script.awk`) to read in all the dictionaries and then decide on input line /^tonic:/ which dictionary to use - but that makes it difficult for any substitutions *before* the tonic: line.

Personally, I'd do the second alternative I list, since that seems the most intuitive *to me*. You should pick the one that's most intuitive *to you* and implement it. If the number or size of files makes these take too much time, you can look to get more creative and efficient in the code. But letting the computer do a little extra work so you don't have to is usually a good tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I couldn't make it work, but with helps from other, we came out with another solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

IFS='
' 
for file in $(grep -l "tonic: C" *.txt); do 
     awk -f script.awk dict0.txt "$file" > "${file%.txt}".hb 
done 

for file in $(grep -l "tonic: C#" *.txt); do 
     awk -f script.awk dict1.txt "$file" > "${file%.txt}".hb 
done
```

etc...

It may not be pretty, but it should do the trick.